# Operating with several items selected with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

If selecting one item `$('.item')` is it possible to reference it inside event-handler using `$(this)`?

1. Howcome I reference items if I will use multiple items selection:

   `$('#form1 td.item, #form2 td.item').event-handler(...{ })`
2. I need to fire an event when for example `#form1 td.item` or `#form2 td.item` losts its focus. How do I do that?

**EDIT**

So will `blur()` fire up on any of selector items:

```
$('#form1 td.item, #form2 td.item').blur(function() {
     // something's there
});
```

?

Comment: If multiple focusable elements are selected and have a blur handler attached, the blur handler will be triggered when either element loses focus, and $(this) will refer to the element that lost focus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you attach an event handler to multiple items, each item will have the handler attached and will trigger it independently, so `$(this)` will refer to whichever item triggered the event

Answer (score 2):

a) The event handler will take on one selected element at a time.

b) bind to "blur"